# filter not working in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

My application is served from this URL -http://t4.gav.com/gui

Now I have added a Servlet filter to filter all requests with /gui/* pattern.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AccessCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>t4.AccessCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/gui/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm not sure why mistake Im doing. If I just give root "/" its working.

Comment: other filter don't call  `chain.doFilter(request, response)` ?

Comment: This is your root app? Is there another web app with content-path "gui"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is served at http://t4.gav.com/gui most probably your context path of your application is /gui. Which means, whatever you configure on your Servlet Filter is relative to this context path. This is why / is working.

Based on your configuration the container will filter the requests on URL /gui/gui/*.

Comment: no, you missunderstood me. What I was a saying is: if your context path is /gui and you put your filter on /gui/* then, the container will concatenate to two of them and try to filter on /gui/gui/*.. but if you do not receive a request on this URL (meaning http://t4.gav.com/gui/gui/) then the filter will never execute

Comment: Got it.. :)..Thanks..but I don't want filter to run on the root path..How can I ignore it..

Comment: if you want the filter to run on every request that is hitting your URL (t4.gav.com/gui) then you have to configure it on /* path.
/* is not the root path it just saying all requests should be filter, which means it will filter t4.gav.com/gui but also t4.gav.com/gui/foo or t4.gav.com/gui/bar

Comment: I added /* and its trying to filter t4.gav.com/gui as well..I don't want the landing page to be fiitered

Comment: if you want everything but your landing page, then you should exclude it from the code. Something like this:
String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (!path.equals("/")) {
//do something, that you do not want to do for your landing page
} 
chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue chain.